# Converting Pandas Python to Pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have code written in pandas that I am being asked to convert to pyspark, but I'm not that familiar with pyspark. I think I've got most of it, but I have a few lines that I can't convert.

The first finds the next start date of an ID field if it exists (the data is sorted so that it is sequential)

```
addmaxdate['next_start'] = pd.NaT
addmaxdate.loc[addmaxdate.ID_combo.eq(addmaxdate.shift(-1).ID_combo), 'next_start'] = addmaxdate.shift(-1).startdate
addmaxdate.loc[addmaxdate.startdate.eq(addmaxdate.next_start), 'next_start'] = pd.NaT
```

The next snippet of code creates a gap column by subtracting the next start column by the end date column.

```
addmaxdate['gap'] = pd.NaT
addmaxdate.loc[addmaxdate.gap.isna(), 'gap'] = addmaxdate.loc[~addmaxdate.next_start.isna(), 'next_start'] - addmaxdate.loc[~addmaxdate.next_start.isna(), 'stopdate']
```

As far as my research goes pyspark has no shift() equivalent, so I'm unsure how to accomplish this in pyspark and get the same result. I don't want to use toPandas() because it so resource-intensive.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: I recommend to look to Koalas: https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ - it may help a lot by providing Pandas compatible API on top of PySpark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.shift(-1).column` in pandas is equivalent to

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

F.lag('column').over(Window.orderBy('another_column'))
```

You need to specify an ordering because Spark doesn't have a concept of index like pandas. As you said

> (the data is sorted so that it is sequential)

you can use the sorting column as `'another_column'` in the above code snippet.

As an example,

```
addmaxdate['next_start'] = pd.NaT
addmaxdate.loc[addmaxdate.ID_combo.eq(addmaxdate.shift(-1).ID_combo), 'next_start'] = addmaxdate.shift(-1).startdate
```

can be translated as

```
addmaxdate.withColumn('next_start',
    F.when(
        F.col('ID_combo') == F.lag(F.col('ID_combo')).over(Window.orderBy('ordering_column')), 
        F.lag(F.col('startdate')).over(Window.orderBy('ordering_column'))
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi! This creates the column I am looking for, but if I include the  .otherwise(
        F.col('next_start') I get a cannot resolve column 'next_start" given input" error. what does that part do?

Comment: @Jw007 oh sorry, that's a mistake, it shouldn't have been there. I'll edit my post